# How can a traveler stay up to date with the immigration requirements of all the countries they plan on visiting?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

While it's fairly easy to search for the laws and customs of different countries just using Google and Wikipedia, it's not so easy to find specific, obscure requirements that visitors may have to comply with *upon entry* — beyond simply acquiring the proper visa.

Case in point: Belarus

I almost found myself in a really bad situation as I came to Belarus last week, having no idea about the required medical insurance and home registration.

Luckily my host mentioned it at the last moment and I took care of it with her help.

**Proof of Belarus Requirements**

*Note: these pages did not appear in my Google search results for "requirements to visit Belarus"*

- http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/formsofstaying/
- http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/info/cc9071395f5f804a.html

Also notice that these two pages aren’t even connected. Even if you found the first page, you’d still have no idea of the second.

The state makes no effort to make these requirements obvious, and the airport mentioned nothing at all, despite checking my passport for visa free eligibility.

**So: what else could I have done to be better informed?**

*Additional note: This is more of an issue for couchsurfers and Airbnb guests because hotels in Belarus seem to do this registration for their guests. But as the sharing economy continues to rise, this type of problem will become more prevalent. Unless your host has informed you of these obscure requirements, you’re in the dark. The airport isn’t telling you. No paperwork will be handed to you on the airplane.*

---

In case it helps anyone: I've posted additional details about Belarus as well as scans of my actual documents, for reference, at http://carlosaugusto.net/belarus-and-its-twilight-zone-at-the-minsk-airport

Comment: Do you actually want a list of special requirements, or is this just a pretext for posting a lengthy rant about Belarus border control?

Comment: @Airsick I think a list of requirements is *essential* to the travel community. We all should have such a list! This is not a rant: this is a valid warning to all travelers and a current serious risk. Belarus opened up to a lot of new countries recently but they're clearly not good at posting up the rules.

Comment: @Airsick Such a list might even need to be crowdsourced because even proactively googling for Belarus travel requirements didn't turn up this info.

Comment: I can see the value of a list of special requirements, even if  it might be difficult to compile and maintain. A call to the local embassy for <destination country> should provide the information for any serious traveller. I don't see what that has to do with the capitalised ranting about the lack of border guards at the airport or the disparaging remarks you make about the officials you did encounter. I'm voting to close because this __is__ a rant.

Comment: @Airsick I'll try to edit it; don't mean to be disparaging

Comment: @Airsick OK, edited. Hopefully it sounds measured and informational now, and not like a rant.

Comment: @Airsick, Great advice as well about making it a default habit to always call the embassy for any country you're visiting to ask about obscure requirements. Even if people just adopt that habit because of reading this, that's totally worth it.

Comment: Note that in just about every country on the planet, *you* are responsible for complying with customs and immigration laws, including obtaining a visa/entry clearance/whatever-they-call-it-there if applicable, regardless of whether or not there is a passport checkpoint.  The checkpoints are only at the airport for reasons of security and convenience.  If the checkpoint is absent or unstaffed, you still have to find an immigration official and submit to whatever formalities the law requires.  If you don't know how to do that, the consular officials in your country's local consulate probably do.

Comment: Your idea of a travel wiki to collect such information is a good one. However travel.StackExchange [has a particular format](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour), and that is not it (nor is cut-n-paste from other sources).  Immigration officials do web searches and  you really don't want your name connected with stuff like that.  It's utterly reasonable to refuse someone entry who openly speaks against your country.

Comment: The information you should have gotten yourself is [right on the pages of the Belarus embassy in Brazil](http://brazil.mfa.gov.by/pt/consular_issues/visas1/). As a traveller, it is *your* responsibility to check these things before your departure. What would have happened if the requirements had changed, you are now required to apply for a visa but trusted all the outdated information on the internet?

Comment: @Harper Ok thank you for the SE format link and fair warning. I think I've edited the information in my question well enough now to no longer be "speaking openly against" but simply factual, presenting the same info that the state's own website presents.

Comment: @Jan Wow, Thank you for that link. So you know what? The takeaway here is that I, and by extension millions of other travelers (via the "I can't be the only one" principle, and maybe also via the "worst education ever" curse, as I grew up in the USA), have NO IDEA that you can't just get a tourist visa and assume you're finished. All children should get a proper travel education and be taught that you must do additional research for each country you travel to and that is only properly done by talking to an embassy representative or finding an official embassy notice as you have.

Comment: @solrac Yeah, sometimes the wrong assumption exists out there that you can just buy/apply for something and it’s good. The opposite is usually true. Pretty sure, for example, that you can buy a car without a driving licence (because it doesn’t have to be you who’s driving). It can also be something ‘absurdly stupid’: in Scandinavia, having a beer in your hand on the street can lead to serious trouble with the police. I recall something about Singapore and you not being allowed to chew gum. Key feature and take home message: *do your research!*

Comment: @Jan Yes, you're absolutely right, and I do search for local customs and laws for the places I travel. The blind spot was thinking that getting a visa is all there is to do, especially when no further info was given to airline passengers or mentioned by airport staff. I thought that if a country really wanted people to comply with something, they'd require the stewards/esses to pass out a notice to everyone on the flight, which I've seen before.

Comment: Whilst this whole thing is one of the most interesting things I've read on the internet in days, I'm not sure if it fits the "rules" of this site ???  I thank you for the info though, @solrac !

Comment: @Fattie It does fit the rules. I asked a specific, answerable question, and spent hours editing the content to fit the community's requirements and suggestions. AND the comments here teach CRUCIAL information that every traveler must know! Sadly and shamefully, now this question is "on hold" and no one else will learn from what I just learned. The world is not a better place and people are still in the dark, and travel.SE blocked critical information from being visible because of minor points — despite them being addressed and corrected.

Comment: @Fattie And to add to that, please suggest how I may edit this further so it's clear what I'm asking and future people may find and learn from this.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea, @solrac.  I think the various "rules" on SO sites are really silly. (But, it's their business - if that's how they want to run it, fair enough.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments (thanks @Jan and @Kevin) under the question provide the correct answer:

Note that in just about every country on the planet, you are responsible for complying with customs and immigration laws, including obtaining a visa/entry clearance/whatever-they-call-it-there if applicable, regardless of whether or not there is a passport checkpoint.

The checkpoints are only at the airport for reasons of security and convenience. If the checkpoint is absent or unstaffed, you still have to find an immigration official and submit to whatever formalities the law requires.

The information about Belarus is on the [pages of the Belarus embassy in Brazil](http://brazil.mfa.gov.by/pt/consular_issues/visas1/), for example.

Since this information is **not** easily found through a Google search and, as a traveller, it is *your* responsibility to check these things before your departure, in order to reliably get the most up to date information you should directly contact a representative of the embassy for any country you plan on visiting.

Comment: Right... People think a cursory search on Google will bring them *all pertinent knowledge*. I call this swiss cheese knowledge.  We see it all the time on diy.se, people *rewire their house* this way: they find a page on MWBCs and get its complex connections picture perfect... but use the wrong wire and splice badly because  **it didn't even occur to them to ask** about that.  It's frustrating because they're plenty smart enough to get it right, they just didn't....... know...

Comment: @Harper So true. Hopefully this question can be reopened now and exist as a small beacon of light to help more people understand this, as it helped me.

Comment: You can post good content, but you can't make people search.

Comment: @Harper Invariably some people *will* search and either find or stumble upon information like this ... and the world will slowly become a better place. Only because of the Internet. Hope this question can be reopened.

Comment: the data is also on your blog, so totally available.

Comment: @Harper Sure, but virtually zero people will find my blog. It mainly serves as evidence that I wrote it.